# Add item to admin bar as late as possible

Tags: admin, admin-bar

I have an admin page in my plugin where I want to show a balance figure in the admin bar.  This works fine for the most part:

```
// in the __construct method    
add_action('admin_bar_menu', array($this, 'admin_bar_item'), 999);

// the method itself
function admin_bar_item($wp_admin_bar){
    $userid = get_current_user_id();
    $display = $this->balance($userid);
    $args = array(
                'id'    => 'balance',
                'title' => $display,
                'href'  => 'http://mysite.com/my-page/',
                'meta'  => array('class' => 'balance_link')
            );
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
}
```

The problem comes when the user does something to update their balance on the admin page - using a `<form>` and `$_POST`-ing the update.  The admin bar fires too soon meaning that the balance displayed in the admin bar is the balance before the $_POSTed amount is processed.  I've tried increasing the priority in the `add_action` hook to 9999999 but it doesn't make any difference.  I don't know what else to try.  How can I make rendering the admin bar the very last thing to happen?

Comment: You can't very easily, really. Wouldn't a better solution be to process the form earlier?

Comment: Possibly.  What's the best method for doing that?

Comment: On what hook are you currently handling the `$_POST` data?

Comment: `add_submenu_page` which calls the method for rendering the page.  The first part of the method called is `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { /* process form */ }`

Comment: Then I would suggest moving that to the `init` action, for example. There's no reason for processing the data that late :-).